# Implement a math command on a list of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I have a set of numbers and would like to do the same math process on all of them. 
Example: 
data1={1,2,3,4,5,6}

Then have each number processed as Log(1), Log(2),.....

This seems like such a simple task, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `Log[data1`] or `Log/@data1` or `Map[Log,data1,{1}]`

Comment: `data1//Log` also works.

Comment: also `Table[Log[d], {d, data1}]`

Comment: `Log@data1` carries the least number of characters. If you want it to evaluate to numerical values just pop in an `N@` at the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

Many of Mathematica's built-in functions have the property that when they are applied on a list they automatically are applied on all the elements of the list.

```
Log[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> {0, Log[2], Log[3]}

This property is called `Listable`:

```
Attributes[Log]
```

> {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected}

User-defined functions do not have this by default (although if they are straightforward combinations of built-in functions, Mathematica may find them `Listable`):

```
h[x_] := x^2 + 3 x - 2
h[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> {2, 8, 16}

For more opaque functions this doesn't work:

```
f[x_] := g[x]
f[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> g[{1, 2, 3}]

You can make them `Listable` by telling Mathematica they are:

```
SetAttributes[f, {Listable}]
f[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> {g[1], g[2], g[3]}